# Microsoft StoreAppLicense understanding the trial logic

Tags: c#, winui

I've had trial capabilities implemented within my application for a little while now; a very simple 1-day full trial for context set within the Microsoft Partner Centre.

I recently got a review that stated some issues when installing my app as a trial related to it immediately expiring. So I wanted to review the logic but I am having some trouble understanding if I've taken a slightly redundant approach to the way I check for valid licences and it's not explicitly clear from the Microsoft documentation the exact logic.

Below is the snippet of code I use to check for a valid trial license:

```
public StoreAppLicense? AppLicense
{
    get; set;
}

public bool IsTrialExpired()
{
     if (AppLicense == null)
     {
         return false;
     }

     // It's expired if it's a trial, it's not active, or the expiration date is in the past
     return AppLicense.IsTrial && (!AppLicense.IsActive || DateTime.UtcNow > AppLicense.ExpirationDate);
}
```

Do I need the date check and are the below assumptions correct?

- (IsActive = True && IsTrial = True) This Means it's under trial and the trial **hasn't** ended.
- (IsActive = False && IsTrial = True) This Means it's under trial, and the trial **has** ended.

In which case, I don't need the date check OR ALTERNATIVELY when the trial expiration date elapses does the IsActive stay true, and I am indeed supposed to do a date comparison. I feel like I'm hedging my bets but without really knowing which is the right combination.

The actual trigger for IsActive changing isn't explicit in relation to the trial-related documentation; I could also be completely missing the paragraph or sentence that clears this all up, in which case, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumptions are indeed correct but as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.istrial?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077), "it can take some hours after the trial period ends for `IsActive` to begin returning a value of `false`".

> While IsTrial returns true, there are two ways to tell whether the trial period has expired:

- If you want to take action the moment the trial period expires then compare the current Coordinated Universal Time (or Zulu time) with ExpirationDate.
- Otherwise, you can check IsActive, which returns true during the trial period and false *some time after* the trial period ends.

Comment: Thank you for this, I must have either skimmed over that, or missed it completley in the docs.